# Synthetic channel creation using linux software

Tags: image-processing, color

I have a RGB image in FITS format (though I can easily convert it to another format if that makes things easier). I wish to use the R, G, B channel data from each pixel in the original image, weighted by a number of constant values a to i, to create a new image with 3 synthetic channels A, B and C:

A = aR + bG + cB

B = dR + eG + fB

C = gR + hG + iB

What is the easiest way to do this? I would prefer a solution using standard open source software such as imagemagick, gimp etc. but if a specific niche piece of software is the only way to go then so be it. Bonus points if the solution makes it easy to apply the transformation to multiple input images in a batch.

Comment: Hm, problem is that we really don't do code to your specification (it's off-topic via the rules), but I guess since you say you want to do this in batches, you're probably already using a programming language? If that's the case, what have you tried within that language? Maybe we can just push you in the right direction (this problem doesn't seem all that complicated, compared to other stuff you often do with FITS imagery (astronomy, remote sensing?)).

Comment: I haven't started anything yet, it's just experimental at the moment though I know in principle if it works I'm likely to want to repeat the process with a number of images. I don't need exact code, just a steer in the right direction. I can figure out a highly laborious way of doing it by decomposing the image in gimp, adjusting the levels for each channel and recombining as required but I'm hoping there's a more flexible and programmable image-wrangling application I can use.

Comment: so, what's your programming language of choice?

Comment: My coding is somewhat rusty but I can manage in C or python if you can point me in the direction of a suitable (and reasonably user-friendly) image processing library, or if there's a graphics application with sufficiently powerful scripting to make the job reasonably easy then that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

So, this sounds pretty doable in Python:

use `astropy`'s FITS interface module to open FITS files.

You can then select the image data object inside your FITS file object. It's just a `numpy` ndarray (n-dimensional array). Chekc its `.shape`! It's probably going to be channels × width × height (or maybe, your RGB channels are different image data objects?).

You can then use `numpy`'s usual splicing operators; for example

```
C = g*data[0::] + h*data[1::] + i*data[2::]
```

would be your method of calculating the desired `C` channel. (note that this assumes your RGB image to simply be three channels in one image object, that's not necessarily the case, FITS can contain lots of different image data types.)